# Cannot resolve org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar - How to use LookupService inside CustomProcessor

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I'm implementing Custom NiFi Processor to decode some files. During the decode process I need to lookup external CSV record for certain data mapping. Note the this decoding process is complex so it has to be a custom processor. I know I can setup external CSVRecordLookupService and then within my CustomController I can define a property descriptor as below

```java
    public static final PropertyDescriptor CLIENT_LOOKUP_SERVICE =
            new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
                    .name("Client CSV Lookup service")
                    .identifiesControllerService(LookupService.class)
                    .required(true)
                    .build();
```

My first problem is How to refer `LookupService.class`, which maven Jar package should I use. After bit of investigation I found this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-services-api-nar/1.13.0. So I added it to my `processors` `pom.xml` as below

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-services-api-nar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now I can compile my class and `LookupService` is visible to the code. However I cannot build the `nar` or run the maven as it gives `Cannot resolve org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:1.13.0` error

in the IDEA it also shows the error

[image]

How to solve this issue and use `org.apache.nifi.lookup.LookupService` in my custom processor.

I believe it probably because it comes as `nar` instead of `jar`. But my question is how do I use LookupService at compile time only and use the NiFi provided classes at run time by solving this issue.

> UPDATE

I'd like to provide an update on this, but the issue is not fully resolved.

I found a jar in [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-service-api/1.13.0) which has the `LookupService`

This together with [org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.Record](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record) I can compile and run the maven successfully.

According to maven repo dependency both these should be declared with the scope `provided`. So I did that.

Now the problem is I cannot package the nar. It doesn't like the I excluded the LookupService class. even if I remove provided scope it doesn't get included as well.

```
[INFO] Generating documentation for NiFi extensions in the NAR...
[INFO] Found a dependency on version 1.13.0 of NiFi API
[ERROR] Could not generate extensions' documentation
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/lookup/LookupService

...
...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugin:1.3.1:nar (default-nar) on project nifi-decoder-processors-nar: Execution default-nar of goal org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugin:1.3.1:nar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugin:1.3.1:nar: org/apache/nifi/lookup/LookupService
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    extension>org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugin:1.3.1
```

So how do we use this LookupService in our custom processors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to make use of it in runtime you must add below dependency in  nifi-decoder-processors-nar's pom file. type is nar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.0</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
```

as for compiler time add below in nifi-decoder-processors-processors ' pom file (I found it in Nar's pom.xml in repository, you may think NAR as collection of dependency)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-lookup-service-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[see this post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-use-one-of-nifi-standard-services-like-DBCPService-in/td-p/179077)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need some clarification, on this Are you saying I should use `nifi-standard-services-api-nar` dependency in my `nifi-decoder-processors-nar` pom.xml

and for compile time I should use other two jars dependencies in my `nifi-decoder-processors-processors` (where the actual processor code resides) pom.xml?

i.e. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-service-api and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record, just for compile time?

Comment: I edited my reply to add compile dependency . I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @yaprakme, yes I also managed to add the `nifi-lookup-service-api` and also `nifi-record` as I needed to use `Record` class, and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following maven command (replace 1.20.0 with your version):

```
dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar:1.20.0
```

This will make sure everything the NAR Mojo needs is in your *local* repository.